# Task complete excel function

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, task

I have a 2 tables one is the DB and other is the UI; My EmployeeDB table is something like this:

```
Name:           Task 1  Task 2 Task 3
John Smith        X       X      X
Alexandra Kole    X       X             
Jane Austin               X
```

And in my UI table I have employee names in the first column, and I want to show the status of whether all the tasks are completed or not. So it has to be something like this.

```
Name:            Status 
John Smith       Complete
Alexandra Kole   Incomplete
Jane Austin      Incomplete
```

I have this formula that I have pasted to the Status column of this table:

```
=IF(EmployeeDB[Name]=B4;IF(OR(EmployeeDB[Task 1]=""; EmployeeDB[Task 2]="";  EmployeeDB[Task 3]="");  "Incomplete"; "Complete"); "n.a").
```

But it only works for the first employee in the status table, for the others, the result is n.a, even though the employee is on the DB.

Could you please state what is the problem, and how it can be fixed?

Comment: So which cell is B4 or better yet, what are its contents?

Comment: B4 is the cell under Name column in the second table: -  which has the employee name (John Smith in this case). And the  formula I have is in the C4 which has to show me the status by checking employee name matches with the one in the DB and if the tasks are completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
=IF(COUNTA(INDEX(DB[[Task 1]:[Task 3]], MATCH([@[Name:]], DB[Name:], 0), 0))=3, "Complete", "Incomplete")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

> Under presumption your data starts at `B2` and ends at let's say `D2`,
>   like so:

[image]

Then the following formula will work.

```
=IF(COUNTA(B2:D2) = COLUMNS(B2:D2), "Complete", "Incomplete")
```

[image]

*This solution is however very simplified, if you want to match the names to specific index, you should use the solution @QHarr provided. This should only illustrate an easy workaround.*

Comment: Thanks, Rawrplus, this seems like a smart solution as well, I went for the @Jeeped's version for the reason you specified.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a nice solution given which avoids volatile Indirect. Here is with indirect

H2 drag down

```
=IF(NOT(COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("ADDRESS",INDEX(A2,MATCH($G2,$A2:$A4,0)))),,1,1,3))),"COMPLETE","INCOMPLETE")
```

Data

[image: Data]